What type of spiral is that on the picture ? and what is the formula of such?
I have found some types of spirals, and when I analysed those I have found, they do not met the criteria to shape the draw desired.
And a observation point, bacause I think spirograph its a wrong name for it, its because spirograph was a tool popularized launched in 1965, so that is that. I dont thinks this ir a fermat spiral (aka fermat coil) or a double archemeadean with polar cordinates.
the "spirograph"
https://postimg.cc/CnHtXGjz
The desire here is the formula do replicate on the paper, or the formula, to do it on illustrator or on a graphic calculator.
the question is to replicate this pattern, what its the spiral name ? and how to to use the formula of such spiral.
